# How to use React Redux useDispatch hook in a RTL test?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-testing-library

I want to test a React component after using a redux dispatch. I am using a custom render function from "test-utils.ts" file:

```
import { ReactElement } from 'react'
import { render, RenderOptions } from '@testing-library/react'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store } from './store/store'
import AppTheme from './theme/AppTheme'

type childrenType = {
    children?: string | JSX.Element | JSX.Element[] | undefined
}

const Providers = ({ children }: childrenType) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppTheme>
                {children}
            </AppTheme>
        </Provider>
    )
}

const customRender = (
    ui: ReactElement,
    options?: Omit<RenderOptions, 'wrapper'>

) => render(ui, { wrapper: Providers, ...options })

export * from '@testing-library/react'
export { customRender as render }
```

Now I want to dispatch an action to change the state before rendering a component in the test.

```
test('renders files section', () => {
    // Do something to dispatch an action...

    render(<ContentSection />)

    const headerElement = screen.getByRole('heading', { level: 2, name: 'Files:' })
    expect(headerElement).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the `store` object and use it to dispatch actions to it, e.g. `store.dispatch`.

It might look similar to the following example:

```
import { act, render } from 'test-utils';
import { store } from './store/store';

test('renders files section', () => {
  render(<ContentSection />);

  act(() => {
    store.dispatch(/* action to dispatch */);
  });

  const headerElement = screen.getByRole('heading', { level: 2, name: 'Files:' });
  expect(headerElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

- `act`: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#act